# Undertow ResourceHandler to return the same file when a path cannot be found

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, undertow

I am using `undertow` to statically serve a react single page application. For client side routing to work correctly, I need to return the same index file for routes which do not exist on the server. (For a better explanation of the problem [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually).)

It's currently implemented with the following ResourceHandler:

```
ResourceHandler(resourceManager, { exchange ->
    val handler = FileErrorPageHandler({ _: HttpServerExchange -> }, Paths.get(config.publicResourcePath + "/index.html"), arrayOf(OK))
    handler.handleRequest(exchange)
}).setDirectoryListingEnabled(false)
```

It works, but it's hacky. I feel there must be a more elegant way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find what I needed in the undertow documentation and had to play with it to come to a solution. This solution is for an embedded web server since that is what I was seeking. I was trying to do this for an Angular 2+ single page application with routing. This is what I arrived at:

```
masterPathHandler.addPrefixPath( "/MY_PREFIX_PATH_", myCustomServiceHandler )
    .addPrefixPath( "/MY_PREFIX_PATH",
        new ResourceHandler( new FileResourceManager( new File( rootDirectory+"/MY_PREFIX_PATH" ), 4096, true, "/" ),
            new FileErrorPageHandler( Paths.get( rootDirectory+"/MY_PREFIX_PATH/index.html" ) , StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND ) ) );
```

Here is what it does:

- the 'myCustomServiceHandler' provides the handler for server side logic to process queries sent to the server
- the 'ResourceManager/FileResourceManager' delivers the files that are located in the (Angular) root path for the application
- The 'FileErrorPageHandler' serves up the 'index.html' page of the application in the event that the query is to a client side route path instead of a real file. It also serves up this file in the event of a bad file request.

Note the underscore '_' after the first 'MY_PREFIX_PATH'. I wanted to have the application API URL the same as the web path, but without extra logic, I settled on the underscore instead.

Answer (score 0):

I check the MIME type for *null* and serve *index.html* in such a case as follows:

```
.setHandler(exchange -> {
    ResourceManager manager = new PathResourceManager(Paths.get(args[2]));
    Resource resource = manager.getResource(exchange.getRelativePath());
    if(null == resource.getContentType(MimeMappings.DEFAULT))
        resource = manager.getResource("/index.html");
    exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, resource.getContentType(MimeMappings.DEFAULT));
    resource.serve(exchange.getResponseSender(), exchange, IoCallback.END_EXCHANGE);
})
```